# tclPort.h:23:28: fatal error: tclUnixPort.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ns2

I am trying to install **ns2 simulator** on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS by following steps mentioned at [The Network Simulator: Building Ns](https://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/ns-build.html).

I downloaded **tcl8.6.7-src.tar.gz** and **tk8.6.7-src.tar.gz** from [link](http://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/download.html).

Installed **tcl** and **tk** properly by following steps mentioned in [link](http://www.tcl.tk/doc/howto/compile.html).

Downloaded **otcl-1.14** from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/otcl-tclcl/files/OTcl/1.14/otcl-src-1.14.tar.gz/download).

But when I tried installing **otcl** , it gives following error when I fire **make** command

[image: fatal error: tclUnixPort.h]

When I checked my **tcl** installation directory I found the **tclUnixPort.h** file in **/home/danny/ns2/tcl8.6.7/unix**. So I modified gcc INCLUDE path in Makefile to include above path.
But still no success in compiling source code of **otcl**. Getting following error..

[image: make error]

Kindly suggest possible solution to resolve this error.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ns-2.35 (otcl ?) cannot use tcl, tk version 8.6.x, I think. Besides that, if you ever need a system wide tcl8.5 - tk8.5 , Ubuntu packages must be used : `sudo apt install tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev`

Your link : old year 2011 text https://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/ns-build.html : No good !

Latest : Get the "2014 - 2017 update" `ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz` → Right versions of tcl tk otcl tclcl are included → 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNVVlxR0ZNRGVORjQ/view?usp=sharing

The build :

```
tar xvf ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz
cd ns-allinone-2.35/
./install
cd ns-2.35/
sudo make install
cd ../nam-1.15/
sudo make install
```

That's it. And you now have `/usr/local/bin/{ nam, ns }`

Note : The Ubuntu 16* `nam` package is corrupt. Don't use.

P.S. : Images with text will not be read. Please use copy-paste for text!

Comment: Last command "sudo make install" giving following error "cannot stat 'nam': No such file or directory, Makefile:166: recipe for target 'install' failed"

Comment: Finally managed to run nam as well.. There was an issue when I try to execute make for nam. It was throwing error xwd.c:87:29: fatal error: X11/Xmu/WinUtil.h: No such file or directory. This error is resolved using following command sudo apt-get install libxmu-dev

Comment: A comment to »»Xmu/WinUtil.h: No such file«« : The basic ns2 build requirements are : `$ sudo apt install g++ autoconf libtool libxmu-dev`